# SolrNet - Is there a way to build a Solr query using a for-loop?

Tags: c#, solrnet

I am testing how `SolrQueryByField` will work using different combinations of indexed fields. So I have an app that has a checkbox for each indexed field and I need to query solr only for the fields that are checked. So is there a way to loop through checkbox controls and add them to the `SolrQuery`? Something like:

```
string query="";
Foreach (var checkbox in checkboxlist)
{

     if(checkbox.checked)
      {
           query += " new SolrQueryByField(checkbox.name)"
       }
}

Solr.Query(query);
```

I am using C#

Comment: @ItayMoav I'm sorry I didn't get what you are asking? If you are asking if I am querying solr on server side, then yes, I am trying to come up with a C# code for doing that.

Comment: `new SolrQueryByField(checkbox.name)` -> this is missing a parameter, either the field or the value. Please clarify.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer sorry about that this should be more like         new SolrQueryByField(checkbox.name, keyword).  Where keyword is what i need to search for in each checked field.

Comment: Also the "checkbox.name" is the name of an indexed field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var queries = checkboxlist
    .Where(x => x.checked)
    .Select(x => new SolrQueryByField(x.name, keyword))
    .Cast<ISolrQuery>();
var query = new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(queries, SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery.Operators.AND);
var results = solr.Query(query, ...);
```

Comment: it worked perfectly, thanks yet again. Following is the final version of the code. Just needed to cast checboxlist as ListItem     var queries = cblFieldsToQuery.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                        .Where(x => x.Selected)
                        .Select(x => new SolrQueryByField(x.Value, query))
                        .Cast<ISolrQuery>();                                         var query = new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(queries, SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery.Operators.AND);
var results = solr.Query(query, ...);